# Why can my site be accessed from two diffrent adress? And why deos it change my font?

Tags: html

I am not that good at explaining so for example (and this is my actual site), http://securityfenceonline.com/ has a different font on the header menus then http://www.securityfenceonline.com/ does. Basically my question here is how do i get the fonts from the site that starts with www to work on the site that doesn't have a www. My second question is why are there two different urls to access the same website. Thank you so much!!

Coded with: HTML

Uses some Joomla

Newbie at coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DNS entries are configured to point both `securityfenceonline.com` and `www.securityfenceonline.com` to the same server.  This isn't uncommon.  What should be happening though is your server should be configured to 301-redirect one to the other.  Otherwise you're creating duplicate content which isn't good for SEO purposes.

The font issue is that you're trying to load a font cross-domain (from www.).  You can't do this without the appropriate CORS headers.  If you look in your developer console, you should see something like:

> Font from origin 'http://www.securityfenceonline.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://securityfenceonline.com' is therefore not allowed access.

If you were to redirect to only one hostname, you wouldn't have this issue.  You really should be referencing files in your CSS by relative paths though, as this would also solve the issue.

Comment: Hey Brad, Thank you for this answer but I am 15 just started making website. I am self taught html and trying to get this website up. I am slowly making progress as this is my first time writing a website in html.

Comment: your explination was a little too complex for me right now, I think I have the gist of how it works now though thank you and if you can tell me how to fix it a little bit easier that would be helpful.                                                                P.S. I want to keep the www. domain name not the naked domain name (securityfenceonline.com)

Comment: @ethanfigliola You need to configure your web server to redirect from `securityfenceonline.com` to `www.securityfenceonline.com`.  I couldn't tell you how to do this because you didn't tell us what web server you are using.

Comment: i am using bravenet. I am pretty sure thats what the web server is thats were all my hosting comes from.

Comment: @ethanfigliola The server claims to be Apache.  Can you modify your config?  Contact Bravenet.

Comment: how did you find out that its apache (just wondering). And thank you so much, Also i can modify the config file what do i put into it.

Comment: You can look in the host response header with your browser's developer tools. Search for mod_rewrite and you will see a ton of examples.

Comment: examples of what? @Brad

Comment: Examples of configuration to redirect from one hostname to another.

Comment: I only found sef_rewrite

Comment: there is no such file that is named mod_rewrite what should i do make one?

Comment: @ethanfigliola No.  Use **Google** or some other search engine, on the internet, to look for mod_rewrite examples.